# How can I use a Custom Property within a Custom Template?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, wpf-controls

Let's say a want to create a custom button that has a small ellipse on the left hand side.
I want the color of this ellipse to be data bindable.

So I fire up Blend and put a button on the surface and `Edit a Copy of the Template`.
I now have my custom template, and I put a small little `Ellipse` inside it:

...

```
<Border x:Name="Background" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="White" CornerRadius="3">
  <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="1">
    <snip   />

    <!-- My ellipse here -->
    <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse" Width="10" Height="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
  </Grid>
</Border>
```

...

I right click this button and select `Make into UserControl` named `MyButton`.
In the code behind for this button I add a custom `dependency property for the`Brush`:

```
public Brush MyColor
{
  get { return (Brush)GetValue(MyColorProperty); }
  set { SetValue(MyColorProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty MyColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyColor", typeof(Brush), typeof(MyButton), new PropertyMetadata(new opertyChangedCallback(MyColorPropertyChanged)));

private static void MyColorPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
  var thisControl = d as MyButton;
}
```

I can then use my custom button:

```
<local:MyButton Width="130" MyColor="Red"/>
```

But then I'm stuck. How do I bind my Ellipse color (x:Name="ellipse" above) to my `MyColor` property?

EDIT: So I bind the Fill property in the user control using `Fill={TemplateBinding MyColor}` , but then I get `Property MyColor was not found in type Button`.
Ok, so I need to target my template to the custom MyButton type, but how can I do that?
I can simply change Button to MyButton, because then I get `Property 'ContentTemplate' was not found in type 'MyButton'`

```
<UserControl
 <snip/>
 x:Class="SilverlightApplication1.MyButton">
  <UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="Button">
      <snip/>
    </Style>
  </UserControl.Resources>

  <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Button Content="Test Button" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}"/>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: @IAbstract, XAML does rule out ASP.NET, doesn't it? What we have left is WPF and/or Silverlight. I think the context is WPF/Silverlight agnostic, hence my XAML tag.

Comment: it is important to have complete tags ...someone might be looking for the same solution but use WPF or Silverlight instead. I'm not that familiar (yet) with Asp.Net - so forgive my ignorance. I do think it is important to provide all tags to which a question applies. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `UserControl` is not the right basis for your control.  You ought to be creating a Templated control.

In Visual Studio add new "Silverlight Templated Control" to your project called `MyButton`.

Open MyButton.cs and change its base class to `Button`.  Drop into the code your `MyColor` dependency property.

Open Themes/Generic.xaml and find the default style that has been placed there for this new `MyButton` control.  Replace the `Template` in that style with your template.  Now the `Fill="{TemplateBinding MyColor}"` in your template will work.

Comment: As with most things, it's easy when you now the right way to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, first of all, your `MyButton` control should have a DependencyProperty, say, `MyColor` -- do you have it? In your template, you should bind to that property using `TemplateBinding`. In the XAML using your control you use it just as you are doing: `<local:MyButton Width="130" MyColor="Red"/>`

It seems that your template is missing the template binding:

```
<Border x:Name="Background" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"...>
    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="1">
        ...
        <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse" Width="10" Height="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 Fill="{TemplateBinding MyColor}" />
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

By the way, `MyColor` should be really a `Brush`, not just a `Color`.

Comment: I have the depencyproperty, as described in my question. When I try to bind the Fill property using {TemplateBinding MyColor} I get "Property MyColor was not found in type Button"

Comment: @Magnus: Than your template's target type is `Button`, whereas it has to be `MyButton`.

Comment: I have tried, question updated. If I change my template targets to MyButton I get another error:Property 'ContentTemplate' was not found in type 'MyButton'.

Comment: @Magnus: I don't see where the problem can be. Could you please post the code of the template? Usually you do this with `<ControlTemplate TargetType="local:MyButton"...`

Comment: thanks for your efforts. I uploaded a test solution here: http://insomniacgeek.com/Downloads/SilverlightApplication1.zip

Comment: @Magnus: ough, the whole solution would be complicated for me, as I don't have Visual Studio at home at the moment. Maybe you could just post the template?

Comment: @Magnus: Okay, I looked into your solution. The error seems to be generated by different line: `<ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" ...` It really tries to reference `ContentTemplate` property of `MyButton`.

Comment: Yes, so how can I implement a ContentTemplate into my custom button? BTW, code posted here: http://insomniacgeek.com/using-a-custom-control-with-custom-template-and-dependency-properties/?preview=true

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4276/discussion-between-magnus-johansson-and-vlad)

Comment: @Magnus: do you need the `ContentTemplate` there at all? If not, just remove `ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"` part. If yes, you need a dependency property `ContentTemplate` of type `DataTemplate` in your `MyButton`.